# Warning while adding Facebook.Contracts.dll

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using Facebook C# SDK 5.0.8 Beta binary build.

When I try to add a reference of Facebook.Contracts.dll to my Windows Phone application I get the following warning:

If you add a reference to a silverlight assembly can cause unexpected behavior of the application.

Is it an error?

Answer (score 2):

nope it's just that the dll was compiled against the desktop version of silverlight.  This doesn't mean that it won't work, and you should be fine assuming that the dll has be tested on the phone.

Comment: The same thing happens if you add System.ServiceModel.Syndication, but it has been working well in production. So, I too, think that as long as your testing doesn't show any inconsistencies you'll be ok.